# How to use data in deck.gl?

Tags: reactjs, deck.gl, react-map-gl

I am new to deck.gl and having some issues.Whenever i try to use API as data like I am trying to use the following api

```
data: 'https://envirocar.org/api/stable/measurements'
```

but it doesn't work or if i put api's data in a json file and put that in my current working
directory it doesn't work for example:

```
data:'../data_file.json'
```

even .csv files doesn't work but when I use data in a array form like following it works.I don't why if anybody knows please help me.

```
data: [
   {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
         "type": "Point",
         "coordinates": [
            6.4847174678758375,
            51.22546715521443
         ]
      }
]
```

I am talking about the data in _renderLayers()

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {StaticMap} from 'react-map-gl';
import DeckGL from '@deck.gl/react';
import {ScatterplotLayer} from '@deck.gl/layers';

const MAPBOX_TOKEN = process.env.MapboxAccessToken; 
const INITIAL_VIEW_STATE = {
  longitude: 6.4847174678758375,
  latitude: 51.22546715521443,
  zoom: 11,
  maxZoom: 16,
  pitch: 0,
  bearing: 0
};

export default class App extends Component {
  _renderLayers() {
    return [
      new ScatterplotLayer({
        id: 'scatter-plot',
        data: 'https://envirocar.org/api/stable/measurements',
        radiusScale: 10,
        radiusMinPixels: 0.25,
        getPosition: d => (d.features.geometry.coordinates),
        getFillColor: [255,0,255],
      })
    ];
  }

  render() {
    const mapStyle = 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9';

    return (
      <DeckGL layers={this._renderLayers()} initialViewState={INITIAL_VIEW_STATE} controller={true}>
        <StaticMap
          reuseMaps
          mapStyle={mapStyle}
          preventStyleDiffing={true}
          mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
        />
      </DeckGL>
    );
  }
}

export function renderToDOM(container) {
  render(<App />, container);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add dataTransform like so:

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  _renderLayers() {
    return [
      new ScatterplotLayer({
        id: 'scatter-plot',
        data: 'https://envirocar.org/api/stable/measurements',
        dataTransform: d => d.features,
        radiusScale: 10,
        radiusMinPixels: 0.25,
        getPosition: d => d.geometry.coordinates,
        getFillColor: [255,0,255],
      })
    ];
  }
```

Also, note the change to getPosition.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to download the data and save it locally.

Comment: I don't think that this provides an answer to the user's question, but circumvents the intended way of operating using the API.